# EF Core: Navigation property not loading related entities despite Include

Tags: c#, sql, mysql, entity-framework

I'm encountering an issue with Entity Framework Core where a navigation property is not being populated, even though I'm using the Include method.

**Relevant code:**

FileRepository:

```
public IEnumerable<Models.Database.File> GetAll()
{
    return _dbContext.Files.Include(f => f.SourceLines);
}
```

Line Model (which SourceLine implements):

```
 public class Line
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Navigation property for the File this Line belongs to
        /// </summary>
        [ForeignKey("FileId")]
        public virtual File File { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column("file_id")]
        public int FileId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Text { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column("lang_id")]
        public int LangId { get; set; }

        // Navigation property for Language
        [ForeignKey("LangId")]
        public virtual Language Language { get; set; }
    }
```

SourceLine model:

```
[Table("source_text")]
    public class SourceLine : Line
    {
        [Required]
        [Column("line_id")]
        public string LineId { get; set; }

        public ICollection<UserSourceLineMapping> UserSourceLineMappings { get; set; }
    }
```

File model:

```
public class File
{
    // ... other properties
    public virtual ICollection<SourceLine> SourceLines { get; set; }
}
```

LocDbContext:

```
public DbSet<File> Files { get; set; }
public DbSet<SourceLine> SourceLines { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            // Configure Project and File relationship
            modelBuilder.Entity<Project>()
                .HasMany(p => p.Files)
                .WithOne(f => f.Project)
                .HasForeignKey(f => f.ProjectId);

            // Configure File and Line relationships
            modelBuilder.Entity<File>()
                .HasMany(f => f.SourceLines)
                .WithOne(l => l.File)
                .HasForeignKey(l => l.FileId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<File>()
                .HasMany(f => f.TranslationLines)
                .WithOne(l => l.File)
                .HasForeignKey(l => l.FileId);
}
```

**Expected behavior:**

When I call GetAll(), I expect the SourceLines collection to be populated with the related source lines for each file, based on the existing records in the database.

**Actual behavior:**

The SourceLines property is always null, even though corresponding records exist in the database.

**Troubleshooting steps taken:**

I've verified that the foreign key relationship between File and SourceLine is configured correctly in OnModelCreating.
I've checked for any errors or exceptions during query execution, but there are none.

I've tried explicitly loading the SourceLines property using Load after fetching the files, but it doesn't make a difference.

I'm using EF Core 6.0.4 with a MySQL Server database.

Any help in understanding and resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your `public IEnumerable<Models.Database.File> GetAll()` should preserve `IQueryable<T>` instead of returning `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Show us a full example where you call `GetAll()` and consume the results.

Comment: Here's a quick example I wrote up:

`List<Models.Database.File> allFiles = _fileRepository.GetAll().ToList();

List<ICollection<SourceLine>> sourcelines = new List<ICollection<SourceLine>>();

foreach(Models.Database.File file in allFiles)
            {
                if(file.SourceLines != null && 
                   file.SourceLines.Any())
                {   
                    sourcelines.Add(file.SourceLines);
  }    
            }`

Which shows through Quickwatch that sourcelines is empty. However there is one File object in allFiles with SourceLines as null.

Comment: Post your code in the question itself. EF works fine and neither has nor needs CRUD classes like "repositories". The `GetAll()` found in such CRUD classes is almost never needed because it loads the entire table in memory. That may be useful in lookup tables but nowhere else. Some CRUD variants return `IQueryable<>` instead of `IEnumerable<>` essentially converting the CRUD class to a very thin wrapper over a DbSet

Comment: Are you sure there are any related rows to begin with? Have you tried running a SQL query to retrieve them directly? BTW if you only wanted the lines grouped by files, there no reason to load each File. That's just one of the huge problems with using such low-level CRUD classes over high level ORMs. `_context.SourceLines.GroupBy(l=>l>FileId).Select(g=>g.ToList())` will return all lines grouped by file

Answer (score 0):

Update your GetAll method in the FileRepository as follows:

```
public IEnumerable<Models.Database.File> GetAll()
{
     return _dbContext.Files.Include(f => f.SourceLines).AsEnumerable();
}
```

Comment: Why would that have any effect? Casting an IQueryable to IEnumerable is the same as calling `AsEnumerabl()` and just as expensive - it loads the entire table in memory

Comment: I figured it out, I had the wrong namespace. I was using System.Data.Entity rather than Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore